# adding a new item with a DateItemField error

Tags: .net, podio

I'm trying to add a new item to one of my apps using `podio.ItemService.AddNewItem`, but i keep getting this error:

> Start and end must both be with time or both must be without time

there are two `DateItemFields` in the app.

```
var my_due_date = myNewItem.Field<DateItemField>("proposal-due-date");
my_due_date.Start = DateTime.Now;
my_due_date.End = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
var my_flight_date = myNewItem.Field<DateItemField>("expected-flight-date");
my_flight_date.Start = DateTime.Now;
my_flight_date.End = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6);
```

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, adding it here in case someone else has the same problem.

Apparently, the existing items in the app didn't have a `Time` value, only `Date`.
Changing the code to contain `Date` only, solved the issue.

This is the working code snippet:

```
var my_due_date = myNewItem.Field<DateItemField>("proposal-due-date");
my_due_date.Start = DateTime.Parse("2017-09-01");
var my_flight_date = myNewItem.Field<DateItemField>("expected-flight-date");
my_flight_date.Start = DateTime.Parse("2018-01-01");
my_flight_date.End = DateTime.Parse("2018-12-31");
```

Comment: A tip: a DateTime value has a Date property, where the time is filtered off (set to 00:00:00)

Comment: @HansKesting I know, but i need dates as inputs from the client.Using the DateTime.Now was just for testing when nothing worked